# Script for running Exe on all files in different sub folders and for capturing the output in text file

Tags: scripts

I have an exe file which takes .jpg as input and returns 4 values as output on the console.

I have many directories and in each of them I have some images. Can you please tell me how to run this exe on all these files and then saving the output in one file (xls or txt or csv)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try this out

## !/bin/bash

i=1
for file in `find / -name *.jpg`
do
echo "File $((i++)) : $file"
$file > your_program | awk '{print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4}' >> my_number.csv
done